# Direct proof for average property of union-closed family

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{A} \subset 2^{\{1, 2, \dots, n\}}$ be a union-closed family of sets (i.e., for any $A, B \in \mathcal{A}$, also $A \cup B \in \mathcal{A}$). In [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/88D85977CB6F33F1FED3827D995E09DD/S0963548302005230a.pdf/an_average_set_size_theorem.pdf) it is established that
$$
\sum_{A \in \mathcal{A}} |A| \geq \frac{1}{2} |\mathcal{A}| \log_2(|\mathcal{A}|).
$$
Is there a fundamentally different proof of this result to the one [given in the cited paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/88D85977CB6F33F1FED3827D995E09DD/S0963548302005230a.pdf/an_average_set_size_theorem.pdf)? In particular, I am looking for a proof which does not require the concept of a filter/upward-closed family.

Comment: This probably doesn't answer your question, but there is a discussion of Reimer's proof in Section 6.4 of "The Journey of the Union-Closed Sets Conjecture" by H. Bruhn and O. Schaudt which may have some pointers to something useful.